# vlookup return #N/A - String of text in lookup cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have an issue. I have 2 large tables of student payments that I need to "reconcile" with each other.

In Table 1, I have students full name, formatted "Smith, John ". I'm using a formula to just return the last name formatted "SMITH".

In Table 2, the students name is at the end of a long string of text which typically looks like this:

VAED TREAS 310   DES:XXVA CH33  ID:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, INDN:COLLEGE I WORK FOR  CO ID:xxxxxxxxxx CCD, PMT INFO:REF*48*CH33 TF VA FILE NO xxxxxxxxx  *TE, RM xxxxxx-xxxxxx JOHN A SMITH   -

Whenever I try to use vlookup for "SMITH", and reference the cell in the second table, I consistently get an #N/A error.

I've uploaded a specific example of what I'm doing [here](http://www.filedropper.com/vlookuplastname).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a column within the same table that returns SMITH. In the workbook you uploaded, your VLOOKUP formula was referencing a load of blank cells so it couldn't find SMITH in the left-hand most column.

I made a couple of changes and re-uploaded the workbook for you here:
http://we.tl/WjDiLtHDnm

Table 1 now has the surname added to the very final column. I adjusted your vlookup formula to now use the index and match functions to do what you were intending. The only reason I didn't use Vlookup is that I put the surname on the far right (Vlookup only works referencing from the left hand most column and returning values in columns to the right).

B